# "image element".onerror method called when not expected

Tags: javascript

Relevant JavaScript source:

```
var e = o3('img');
e.className = "c";
e.name = "bo_im";
e.src = b.href + 'favicon.ico';
e.onerror = i3d(e);


function i3d(a) {
  a.src='http://www.archemarks.com/favicon1.ico';
}
```

what about

```
e.onerror = function(a) { a.src='http://www.archemarks.com/favicon1.ico'; };
```

`o3()` creates the image element.  I set the object properties in the second line.  I expected `i3d` to run only when the image does not load, i.e. when no favicon is provided by the web site.

When I place onerror in the image element (via inline registration) this is how it works - as I expected.

However, when I put it in the javascript as shown above it is called everytime a new image is created.  I need it to call only when the image is not loaded as `i3d` changes the `src` to a generic image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
var e=o3('img');
e.className="c";
e.name="bo_im";
e.onerror=i3d;
e.src=b.href+'favicon.ico';
```

`onerror` needs to JUST be assigned a function, not the result of calling a function.  You don't need to pass `e` to the function.  The `this` pointer will be set to the img (which is `e`) if `i3d` gets called.

And, you need to set `.onerror` before assigning `.src` as it can get triggered when you assign .src.

Also, I hope you're using variable names like `e`, `c` and `b` only in the example here and not in real code because they do not help to make your code very readable, descriptive or understandable.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are setting `onerror` to be the value of `i3d(e)` rather than actually binding the function to `onerror`.

I think you want something like this:

```
e.onerror=i3d.bind(e)
```

Comment: ok I put in the () so this changed it from a reference to the function it self.

Comment: The first param of `bind` is the "this" object. So within the function you can do `this.src='favicon'`

Comment: @Chris - Yes I believe that is correct. You can use `this` instead of `e`